# While deploying war File into tomcat getting below error

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

When i try to deploy war file into tomcat which hosted on AWS, I am getting below error. Before it was working fine, recently facing this issue, Please help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks.

```
20-Nov-2019 05:11:41.728 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/apis]
20-Nov-2019 05:11:41.779 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [apis] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
20-Nov-2019 05:12:11.843 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/u01/tomcat/webapps/apis.war]
20-Nov-2019 05:12:13.962 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/u01/tomcat/webapps/apis.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)



20-Nov-2019 05:24:35.542 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Nov-2019 05:24:35.564 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/u01/tomcat/webapps/apis.war] has finished in [43,926] ms
20-Nov-2019 05:25:11.560 SEVERE [ajp-nio-8009-exec-143] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage.processHeader Invalid message received with signature [18245]
20-Nov-2019 05:25:11.850 SEVERE [ajp-nio-8009-exec-146] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage.processHeader Invalid message received with signature [5635]
20-Nov-2019 13:22:01.921 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-173] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:415)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:292)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.665 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-531] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.672 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-532] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.678 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-533] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.684 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-535] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.691 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-529] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.699 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-538] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.705 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-537] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.711 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-534] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.717 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-536] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.723 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-530] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.729 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-531] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.735 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-532] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.741 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-533] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
20-Nov-2019 13:44:16.746 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-535] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Hello Santosh-17, please edit the code format, I don't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens

This may occurr when requests are made between two different application protocols (HTTP and HTTPs). Try using HTTP everywhere to see if this was the source of the problem then properly configure all your servers to work with HTTPs if that is what you want